# How to get Cases, Opportunities, Contacts Associated with Account Object Dynamically?

Tags: apex, soql, account, dynamic-soql

I need to get all the associated Contacts,Opportunities and Cases, for a given Account, if there are any.

Right now, I am doing something like below:

```
public List<Case> getCases(SObject sobj){
    List<Case> casesList = [SELECT (SELECT Id,Status,CaseNumber FROM Cases) FROM Account WHERE Id=:(String)sobj.get('Id')].Cases;
    return casesList;
}

public List<Case> getContacts(SObject sobj){
    List<Contact> contactsList = [SELECT Id,(SELECT Id,Name FROM Contacts) FROM Account WHERE Id=:(String)sobj.get('Id')].Contacts;
    return contactsList;
}

public List<Case> getOpportunities(SObject sobj){
    List<Opportunity> opportunitiesList = [SELECT Id,(SELECT Id,Name FROM Opportunities) FROM Account WHERE Id=:(String)sobj.get('Id')].Opportunities;
    return opportunitiesList;
}
```

Is there any better and efficient way to achieve this using dynamic apex??

Can somebody give directions on how to tackle this?

I am guessing this can be simplified alot using dynamic apex but I am not sure on where to start.. Any clues??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Dynamic apex will not help in this case. May be you can try query like this.

```
SELECT id, 
 (SELECT Id,Status,CaseNumber FROM Cases), 
 (SELECT Id,Name FROM Contacts), 
 (SELECT Id,Name FROM Opportunities) 
FROM Account WHERE Id='XXXX'
```

So you will save on number of SOQL. you should check the performance of this query with read data.